# semanage fcontext is not overwriting default policies

Tags: selinux

I'm trying to make some custom policy on selinux file context, but the default is not changing. Here is my commands:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/home/(.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/home/.*/logs(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_tmp_t "/home/.*/tmp(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_var_run_t "/home/.*/tmp/session(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_cache_t "/home/.*/tmp/opcache(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_cache_t "/home/.*/tmp/wsdlcache(/.*)?"
```

And running that command after

```
restorecon -Rv /home
```

But at **/home/anyuser** I run the command **ls -lZ** and the output is:

```
drwxr-xr-x. user group unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 logs
drwxr-xr-x. user group unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 sub.domain.tld
drwxr-xr-x. user group unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 public_html
drwxr-xr-x. user group unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 tmp
```

Just the **logs** and **tmp (inside)** working, and the other nothing changes. Why? My **file_context.local** just have that settings, and its a clean CentOS 7.x install.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I dont understand why...but I made a fresh install and configure all the system again, and with the same commands the Selinux is working perfect.